# Do we know from TNG canon that Geordi La Forge wore no underwear?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

In the recent comedic skit [Star Trek Trivia – Sir Patrick Stewart vs Mayor Pete Buttigieg](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NBRqQ78U3Pk) actor LeVar Burton quizzed Sir Pat and Mayor Pete on Star Trek TNG trivia.

> Burton: For our final question, here we go, for “all the marbles”;
>
> Did my character Geordi La Forge of Star Trek wear boxers or briefs?
>
> Buttigieg: Boxers?
>
> Burton: Nah, wrong.
>
> Stewart: Oh, I know. Nothing!
>
> Burton: That’s correct!

Do we know from TNG canon that La Forge wore no underwear?

---

Cued at `05:02` for *the final question* Caution! **lower volume first,** it's TV.

Comment: Burton played LaForge. If anyone would know what he's wearing under his uniform, he'd be the one, as would someone who shared a dressing room with him

Comment: It might be related to those very tight Season 1 uniforms. To avoid visible pants lines, perhaps.

Comment: I actually would be interested in seeing a *real* quiz show faceoff between Sir Patrick and Mayor Pete.

Comment: This makes me wonder what Starfleet Regulations has to say about underwear.

Comment: Who knew there was a memory alpha page about underwear? https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Underwear It doesn't mention TNG though. I personally can't recall any scene in TNG with actual underwear on screen. There's some scenes with someone wearing some sort of nightgown or pajamas, or various states of undress. Picard even appears fully nude at one point, though from behind with convenient lighting.

Comment: The best I can think is there are I believe there are scenes where a discarded uniform is discovered (Best of Both Worlds and possibly Identity Crisis?), and I don't recall seeing any underwear in those scenes, probably because they didn't want to show underwear onscreen, but it kind of accidentally implies no one wore underwear.

Comment: @Kai thanks, it could have been mentioned in dialogue instead, and I suppose that these guys could be simply pulling our leg.

Comment: @Uhoh I don't know anything at all about what the character Geordi La Forge wore or didn't as underwear, since the actor Levar Burton's outerwear was opaque and I don't remember any mentions of the subject in the 178 episodes.    Therefore, writing "we know" is inaccurate, since I am part of "we" and I don't know.  For all that I know the skit is the only source for that data, and the Jimmy Kimmel Show is not part of Star Trek canon.

Comment: M.A.Golding I've slightly adjusted the wording accordingly, thanks!

Comment: @M.A.Golding negatives are hard to prove; in this particular case if you posted an answer to that effect and nobody objected I'd be inclined to accept.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Out of universe, they wore briefs

In the featurette "Dressing the Future" (Available on [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=1&v=W0XE60K0QA8&feature=emb_title), relevant part starts at the 3 minute mark) we can see Marina Sirtis holding up something she explicitly introduces as Briefs, which men wore on set.
She does not know if LeVar Burton wore them, but since it's a well known fact that the Spandex uniforms "hid nothing", it seems very likely that he did.

> **SIRTIS**: Moving along... My second favorite item: **The Men's Support Briefs**! Because the men can't have a VPL, a visible panty line - I actually have never seen these before so I am as interested as you are... oh my goodness, okay... um, I don't know who exactly wears these, but they have a lot of them, so... maybe a few of my fellow thespians wear them.

[image: Marina Sirtis holding Men's support briefs]

### Uniforms are form-fitting

The TNG-Era uniforms are made of Spandex, at least out of universe, and Gene Roddenberry himself has referred to Spandex as "the fabric of the future". Spandex is very form-fitting and hides nothing, which is what the TNG cast found out during filming.s.

This means that if Geordi wore nothing underneath, we would have... seen something, unless the in-universe uniforms have been altered to not be form fitting below the waist.

### Men's underwear is still a thing in Star Trek

Maybe Geordi wore no underwear because in the future, we won't need no underwear?

That is not the case - we sometimes see underwear in the Star Trek universe. Here is an example which is in-universe in the same era as Geordi.

In the Voyager episode "Twisted", we see B'Elanna running into a crewman who wears nothing but briefs. These look a lot like the men's support briefs the actors are wearing out of universe!

[image: Torres running into a half naked crewman]

So Spandex-like uniforms are a thing in-universe, as well as briefs which are hiding panty lines and other things.

### The canon doesn't give us more than this

At no point is Geordi's habit of (not) wearing underwear discussed or shown on screen. There is also no situation where underwear should have been visible, but is not.

### Conclusion

My personal conclusion, backed by nothing else, is: If Geordi wore no underwear, his colleagues would have seen it in-universe, and we would have seen it, too. Probably LeVar Burton used the Rule of Funny when accepting Stewart's answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for this thorough investigation/review of Trek undergarments in and out of universe! I usually let answers go around the planet a few times but if I forget to accept in a few days ping me!

Comment: An excellent answer (very well referenced) and definitely worthy of an upvote.

Comment: @uhoh here's the ping you requested :)

Comment: @PhilippFlenker and a pleasing ping at that considering the image presented when I clicked on the message notification! Thanks again